# Javascript wysiwyg editor with image upload functionality (use with JEditable)

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a good wysiwyg editor with image upload functionality (i.e. a user can add as many pictures as he likes, form URL's or disk, and they'll be uploaded).

I already tried TinyMCE, but it was really heavy and took a very long time to load (I'm using JEditable to only make the editor appear when the user clicks on it).

Answer (score 1):

I've used the components from dhtmlx.com and had pretty good success with them.  You can buy the libraries or use the open source version of them if your project qualifies.

You can find the editor library here: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxEditor/index.shtml